# Filter objects based on related objects

Tags: python, django, filter

So I have a form where user can post `Parent` details also form for Kid for a different model.

what i need is to allow users to access list of `Parent` objects by filtering their related objects `Kid`

let's say a filter to list Parents objects that has children named `X` older than `Z` live in `Y` city AND has no children named `X` who is younger than `Z` live in `Y` city .

**models.py** :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Kid(models.Model):
    cities = (
        ('city1', city1),
        ('city2', city2)
    )
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(choices=cities)
```

**Views.py** :

```
def index(request):
    my_pattern = (
    (name=samy, age_lt=15, city=paris),
    )
    filter_ids = Kid.objects.filter(my_pattern).values_list('parents_id', flat=True).distinct()
    exclude_ids = Kid.objects.exclude(my_pattern).values_list('parents_id', flat=True).distinct()
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=filter_ids).exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'parents': parents}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

as the views.py shows i listed the pattern as a tuple but didn't work!

i am also wondering if this is the way to do django Q objects except for adding Q in the beginning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_pattern` should be dictionary, and you need to use `**` unpacking in filter and exclude.

```
def index(request):
    my_pattern = {'name': 'samy', 'age__lt': 15, 'city': 'paris'}
    filter_ids = Kid.objects.filter(**my_pattern).values_list('family_id', flat=True).distinct()
    exclude_ids = Kid.objects.exclude(**my_pattern).values_list('family_id', flat=True).distinct()
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=filter_ids).exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'parents': parents}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

If you have mutiple patterns, then you need to use `Q` objects

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def index(request):
    patterns = [
        {'name': 'samy', 'age__lt': 15, 'city': 'paris'},
        {'name': 'sally', 'age__gt': 20, 'city': 'london'}
    ]
    filter_q = reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda p: Q(**p), patterns))
    filter_ids = Kid.objects.filter(filter_q).values_list('family_id', flat=True).distinct()
    exclude_ids = Kid.objects.exclude(filter_q).values_list('family_id', flat=True).distinct()
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=filter_ids).exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'parents': parents}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: I got this error : Cannot resolve keyword 'age_lt' into field. Choices are: age, city, family, family_id, id, name
Also I am wondering if "patterns" items are included. what is going to be excluded?!

Comment: @DjangoGuy lookups should contain double underscore `__`, like this `age__lt`

Comment: the error is fixed. and now there's this error Cannot resolve keyword 'parents_id' into field. Choices are: age, city, family, family_id, id, name

Comment: I changed it to family__id and it seems to be working

Comment: @DjangoGuy oh sorry. In your case it should be `family_id` not `parents_id`.

Comment: how about if I want parents objects to appear as long as their children are all listed in the pattern instead of all of them having to be in the pattern?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694197/filter-objects-if-all-its-foreignkeys-are-in-a-dictionary here i specified my question further wish for an answer.. cheers