# Filter objects if all its foreignkeys are in a dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, filter, foreign-keys

what i need is to allow users to access list of `Parent` objects by filtering their related objects `Kid'

We have a dictionary that has a 100 kid. and parents that have about 5 kids in average.
if the kids in 1 parent object are all in the dictionary I want them to be listed.
But not all 100 kid have to be related to the parent object.

e.g if the parent have 4 kids who are in the dictionary and 1 that is not. Then do not include them.

I have the code below

**models.py** :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Kid(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**Views.py** :

```
def index(request):
    patterns = [
        {'name': 'samy', 'age__lt': 15, 'city': 'paris'},
        {'name': 'sally', 'age__gt': 20, 'city': 'london'}
    ]
    filter_q = reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda p: Q(**p), patterns))
    filter_ids = Kid.objects.filter(filter_q).values_list('family__id', flat=True).distinct()
    exclude_ids = Kid.objects.exclude(filter_q).values_list('family__id', flat=True).distinct()
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=filter_ids).exclude(id__in=exclude_ids)
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'parents': parents}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

so with my current view function shown above. all the kids have to be in 1 parent!!!

help please!

Comment: Where is the dictionary with 100 kids?

Comment: doesn't exist in the example . I meant I want to make  a list/dictionary of items that i want the objects be filtered by

Comment: I guess then I really didn’t understand your question because it sounded like your question stated that you already “have a dictionary that has a 100 kid.”  Sorry.  Good luck!

Comment: I've actually tested your code and it worked perfectly for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do if I understood your question correctly.

```
def index(request):
    patterns = [
        {'name': 'samy', 'age__lt': 15, 'city': 'paris'},
        {'name': 'sally', 'age__gt': 20, 'city': 'london'}
    ]
    filter_q = reduce(operator.or_, map(lambda p: Q(**p), patterns))      
    qs = Kid.objects.filter(filter_q).values_list('id', 'family_id') 
    family_ids = set()
    child_ids = list()
    for child_id, family_id in qs:
        family_ids.add(family_id)
        child_ids.append(child_id)        
    # At this point we have the complete list of matching Kid(s) in child_ids
    # . . . and we have a list of all family IDs in which those Kid(s) exist
    # Now we look for incomplete families, 
    # i.e., families that were part of the first query, 
    # but have Kid(s) that are not in our complete list 
    # of matching kids.
    incomplete_family_ids = set(Kid.objects.exclude(id__in=child_ids).filter(family_id__in=family_ids).values_list('family_id', flat=True).distinct())
    # Now we find the set complement to make life on the database a little easier.
    complete_family_ids = family_ids - incomplete_family_ids
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=complete_family_ids)
    template = 'index.html'
    context = {'parents': parents}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: just to elaborate more. What if the field 'name' is a foreginkey to Name model can it be done?

Comment: Yes, but we would need to see the `Name` model definition to make sure we are matching on the right filter.  But essentially, you would change `'name'`in `patterns` to `'name__field_to_match'` (e.g., `'name__first_name'`)

Comment: class Name(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

Comment: Then change `'name'` in patterns to `'name__title'`